# What is the shortcut to continue script execution in Firebug on Mac?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I know using Windows we only need to press <kbd>F8</kbd> to continue a breakpoint. Though in Mac OS X <kbd>F8</kbd> doesn't seem to work. I tried <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>, too, but that also doesn't work.

So what is the correct keyboard shortcut for continuing the script execution when halted on a breakpoint?

Comment: Depending on your system preferences, you may need to press the `Fn` key when to send `F8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>F8</kbd> on Mac, too, as you can see in the [shortcuts page in the Firebug wiki](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Keyboard_and_Mouse_Shortcuts#Script_Panel). But if you have the *Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys* option unchecked in the Keyboard system preferences, you'll need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to send it.